# The confirm delete button on my modal isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a pop up modal for my delete button on a page. When you clicked on the delete button, a modal will pop up and ask you whether you really want to delete the item or not. There are two buttons on the modal, the first one is cancel and the other one is delete. Clicking on the cancel button will close the pop up but when i click on the delete button, nothing happens.

Here is the php code for the delete button:

```php
echo "<a href='#myModal' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal'> Delete</a>";
```

Here is the modal code:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
        </div>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will not delete automatically. You will have to write a code to delete something that you need.

Comment: where is your delete function?

Answer (score 1):

you have not given anything on click of the delete button and how you are expecting something? if you add data-dismiss="modal" for button it will close the popup. rest of the things u can handle it using javascript.

```js
function Delete()
{

//Write your code for deleting 
  $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     datatype: "json",
     async: false,
     contenttype: "application/json",
     url: "DeleteItem.php",
     success: function (result) {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide'); //for hiding popup 
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          //handle error
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="icon-box">
<i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
</div>              
<h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>  
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Delete()" id="confirm">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i type the delete function? I have the delete query in another file call DeleteItem.php

Comment: @Tips using ajax.

Comment: @Tips I've modified my solution check.

Comment: Is it possible to use <a href> inside the <button> to direct over to DeleteItem.php?